# SVN add hidden files and commit it via bash script

Tags: shell-script, subversion

The is following part of bash script I wrote to automate adding users and save them to SVN.

```
cd $workdir
svn add --username $u .first_$myuser
svn ci --username $u work_place1 work_place2 .first_$myuser
```

The script works fine but I am facing the following problem, when I try to execute the script a `nano` window will appear contains

> --This line, and those below, will be ignored--
>
> A    .first_$myuser

I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then enter <kbd>C</kbd> to continue and everything works like charm. My question is there a way to add a hidden file without this pop up window, if not how can I automate my script to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> without exiting the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a *log message* to svn `ci` and `commit` commands.

```
If you fail to specify either the --message (-m) or --file (-F) option, 
Subversion will automatically launch your favorite editor for composing 
a log message.
```

See [Commit Your Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit) paragraph of [Version Control with
Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) book for some examples.